# Reshaping lat/lon data to 2D matrix in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have an array of **regularly spaced** data in the form `lats`, `lons`, `values`. My `lats` vary from -90 to 90 with step size 1, and my longitudes from -180 to 180 with step size 1.

I want to generate a matrix where all values are 0 except values defined at the latitudes and longitudes. What is the best way to do this? My attempt is:

```
lats=np.array([-85,-43,2])
lons=np.array([-44,-66,24])
values=np.array([1,2,3]) #some random data and points

matrix=np.zeros((181,361))

for i in lats:
  for j in lons:
    matrix[i][j]=values[]
```

but I'm not sure what indexing to use for the variable `values`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we know that index (0,0) is latitude -90 and longitude -180. To convert your longitude and latitude values to indices, add 90 to the latitude value and 180 to the longitude value. This goes off of your specification that the coordinates will all be integers.

Example code:

```py
import numpy as np

lats = np.array([-85,-43,2])
lons = np.array([-44,-66,24])
values = np.array([1,2,3])

coords = np.stack((lats, lons))
offset = np.array([90, 180])
indices = coords + offset[:, None]

matrix = np.zeros((181,361))
matrix[*indices] = values
```